# Internet Slow on Fedora 23

Tags: fedora, wifi

I am new to linux and decided to go with `Fedora 23` on my new laptop, a Thinkpad `T460s`.

I installed `Fedora 23` and the wireless has been disappointing so far. My kernel version is `4.4.6-300.fc23.x86_64`.

I ran SpeedTest.net on my rMBP and my Thinkpad.

On my rMBP I got `12.2 Mbps` down and on my Thinkpad I got `0.91 Mbps` down from the same location.

The Thinkpad is showing ~50-60% wireless connectivity.

I know this is a general question, but I honestly have no idea where to start on how to debug this. Should I start poking around the RedHat bug reports? Are there linux commands that will help me debug this?

EDIT: Here is the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`:

```
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet
Connection I219-V [8086:1570] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:2233]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
--
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260
[8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0130]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

Comment: What wireless card?  Please edit the question to include `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`

Comment: Might it be a hardware problem? Can you dual boot into Windows and compare? Do you see the same slow speed when connecting by ethernet?

Comment: Could be. I installed `Fedora 23` as my main workstation and got rid of windows so I would have to create a partition and install. I'll try ethernet right now.

Comment: @Sparhawk very fast on ethernet. Also shows 100% connectivity.

Comment: Okay. Obviously, it could still be the wifi hardware. I'm not sure how Windows works, but can you boot into a "live DVD" and not bother installing/partitioning? You could also use an Arch Linux, Ubuntu, etc. live DVD, and test their wifi drivers. However, if you see similar slow speeds, it wouldn't be very informative (i.e. could still be Linux *or* hardware).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An old [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1319630) indicates that a performance gain can be achieved using

```
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwl11n.conf
```

Reboot

This option actually doesn't disable anything but enables aggressive TX

Also check the encryption of the wireless access point

```
iwlist scan | egrep -i 'ssid|cipher'
```

You want to see this below your access points ESSID

```
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
```

If you see TKIP, it will cause problems.  Most routers will have a encryption setting to disable TKIP usually called WPA2-AES, WPA2 only, or WPA2-PSK

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. It feels a bit faster but unfortunately the same test is still giving me ~1.5Mbps on my Thinkpad where I get 18-19 on my rMBP. Doesn't look like this was the key.

Comment: I just saw your updated post now. It fixed the issue for me, I can't thank you enough! Is TKIP just bad news with the new cards?

Comment: TKIP has been causing problems for a while, it even has some problems with Windows

Comment: Changed to wpa2-aes. Didn't help

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is and old thread, but i found it and it helped immensely on fedora 28 desktop. The aggressive TX mod worked temporarily, but the real problem was the TKIP. If you have administrator access to your router, you can change the security to wpa2 (AES).